# The prefix "xsd" for element "xsd:element" is not bound. [11]

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, xsd

So I have a task to complete for Friday involving creating a shares system and I'm completely lost in Netbeans. I've used it once before and did reasonably well but I've been stuck on this same issue for 2 hours now.

I've obviously gotta create the XML and accompanying schema for this project but started from a blank XSD now, I can't validate the code and also have troubles to create the constrained XML document from the XSD as there isn't a primary Element. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be a great help. Me and Netbeans do not seem to get along. The XSD is as follows and yes, it's probably something completely obvious.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="shares">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CompanyName" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="CompanySymbol" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="AvailableShares" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Updated" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:element name="Currency" type="xsd:float"/>
                <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:float"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The xml only declared the namespace `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` but uses instead the prefix `xsd`.

Also the closing `</xsd:schema>` is missing.

Here is the fixed xml:

```
<xsd:schema version="1.0"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="shares">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CompanyName" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="CompanySymbol" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="AvailableShares" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="Updated" type="xsd:date"/>
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:element name="Currency" type="xsd:float"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:float"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited it to validate as the above does not validate for me and have managed to get it to validate now. Seems like my lecturers notes are a little off. Thanks for the help, I was starting to get a little blind with frustration as to why. the simple things. Now to force Netbeans to generate the XML as that isn't liking it xD